# is it possible to draw a line with a "gap" using lightweight-charts?

Tags: lightweight-charts

struggling with this one a little bit, want to draw a line with a "gaps" something like that:
[image]

but whatever i did so far chart either skips "missing days" and joins "last before gap" and "first after gap" either interprets values as 0 (NaN, null tested). Is it even possible to have a "gap" there?

examples:

1. nulls or nans work like this:
   [image: nulls or nans]
2. no days at all:
   [image: no days at all]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible right now. As workaround you can create several separate series for each piece of the line.

But I think it's better to create an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues).

Comment: Thanks, just as i thought. We already started this "split" i was just hoping there isn a better solution for that.